# Displaying line breaks in the response text

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I use Swagger UI v2.2.0. I have a RESTful method which returns plain text. I want to display this text with line breaks.

At the moment, the returned text contains new line characters, but they are displayed as `\n`. The `Content-Type` response header is `text/plain`.

[image]

I can return the text with something else inserted of new line characters (e.g., `<br>` tags). I also can change the `Content-Type`. I just need actual line breaks in the displayed text.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you referring specifically to rendering it with the Swagger UI tool, or do you have flexibility to present your Swagger (OpenAPI Spec) using a different tool?

Comment: @busse I use Swagger UI. I clarified my question.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it helps, but I also faced the same issue.

I wanted to execute the following code in nodejs server:

```
app.post('/xyz', function (req, res) {
    res.status(400).send("MyError\nMyErrorStack:\nStackLine1\nStackline2")

}
```

and wanted output like:

```
"MyError
MyErrorStack:
StackLine1
Stackline2"
```

but got :

"MyError\nMyErrorStack:\nStackLine1\nStackline2"

so instead i split the string into array as shown used following:

```
err.error = errObj.stack.split("\n")

app.post('/xyz', function (req, res) {
    res.status(400).send(err)

}
```

and this printed

```
"Error": {    
    "error": [
      "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\\....'",
      "    at Error (native)",
      "    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)",
      "    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1224:33)",
      "    at Object.fs.appendFileSync (fs.js:1283:6)",
      "    at ...",
      "    at ...",
      "    at ...",
      "    at ...",
      "    at ...",
      "    at ..."
    ]
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible due to a documented bug in Swagger UI. Reference:

[Inconsistent Markdown Newlines #2981](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2981)

[Bug in Model (Definition) Description with newline characters #3078](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3078)

The second Issue listed, #3078 contains some discussion on overriding the styles used to render that part of the UI, but results appear inconsistent.

*Note: I have subscribed to those issues and will update the answer and/or flag to close as no longer relevant when it is resolved.*