# JSON/Nodejs/swagger: Newlines not translated to multi-line in strings of express response displayed in swagger

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I am working on a nodejs server sending back JSON as responses via an express reference and displaying to swagger ui client for display. Some of these responses can be log and might contain error stack so I wanted to display the stack in multi-lines. But i tried all sorts of characters viz. `\n, \r\n, \\n, <br>(wild guess)` but nothing worked.

Sample code:

```
app.post('/xyz', function (req, res) {
    res.status(400).send("MyError\nMyErrorStack:\nStackLine1\nStackline2")
}
```

Displays in swagger browser client as:

```
"MyError\nMyErrorStack:\nStackLine1\nStackline2"
```

Instead of:

```
"MyError
MyErrorStack:
StackLine1
Stackline2"
```

Is there some solution for this or am i using the wrong characters?

Comment: Please remove duplicate tag as i have a workaround for this.

Comment: This question is more easily searchable than the original one so I wanted to add an answer to it. The comments section is too small to add the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is duplicated but the answer is to split up the string by the delimiting character and send back as an array. Since this is duplicated, this the best i can write, though i have added an answer in the original question in a more elaborate way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Similar issue to what is described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162608/displaying-line-breaks-in-the-response-text). Answer:

This is due to a documented bug in Swagger UI. Reference:

[Inconsistent Markdown Newlines #2981](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2981)

[Bug in Model (Definition) Description with newline characters #3078](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3078)

The second Issue listed, #3078 contains some discussion on overriding the styles used to render that part of the UI, but results appear inconsistent.

*Note: I have subscribed to those issues and will update the answer and/or flag to close as no longer relevant when it is resolved.*